# Draw image based on 4 points in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a list of 4 points, and an angle, in radians.

The list of points could be in any rectangular shape, eg:

```
           __(x,y)
(x,y)__--**  |
  |          |
  |        __(x,y)
(x,y)__--**
```

Or...

```
(x,y)--------(x,y)
 |             |
 |             |
 |             |
 |             |
(x,y)--------(x,y)
```

Anyways, the point is, the points can be angled.

These points are stored in a list (`points`), and the angle is given in radian (`body.angle`)

Currently, my logic uses the bounds of the object (in matter.js... this is not important, just provided for some background) and stores them in a `coordinate` variable.

```js
this.coordinates = [this.body.bounds.min.x,this.body.bounds.min.y];
```

Then, in my draw function, I use those coordinates to draw the image:

```js
var x = this.coordinates[0] - camera[0] + this.width/2;
var y = this.coordinates[1] - camera[1] + this.height/2;
var rotation = this.body.angle;
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x, y); // move the canvas to the coordinates
ctx.rotate(rotation); // rotate the image
ctx.drawImage(this.source, -this.getWidth() / 2, -this.getHeight() / 2, this.width,this.height);

// Reset the transformations for future drawings
ctx.rotate(-rotation); // unrotate/transform
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
ctx.restore();
```

This, however, seems to not work properly, and I cannot figure out why.

In this image the sprite appears to be rendering correctly, but once you move it to make it collide with other object and introduce some angle, everything starts to get skewed.

[image: square sprite]

In the following images, you can see the true shape (easily drawn with canvas.lineTo on each of the points) as an outline, and the image itself does not fit with the outline

[image: not lining up][image: not lining up again][image: and not lining up again]

The code can be found at https://replit.com/@sojs/Anvil#script.js

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var points = [[50,50],[75,25],[100,50],[75,75]]
var points2 = [[150,150],[200,150],[200,200],[150,200]]
var pAngle = -Math.PI/4; // (negative b/c canvas origin is top left, not bottom left- cos doesnt change with negative theta, only sin does, so doesnt impact X coord of point)

var angledPoint = [75+20*Math.cos(pAngle),50+20*Math.sin(pAngle)];

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(this.points[0][0], this.points[0][1]);
for (var point of points) {
  ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillRect(angledPoint[0]-5,angledPoint[1]-5,10,10);

// points 2 (unangled)
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(this.points2[0][0], this.points2[0][1]);
for (var point of points2) {
  ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillRect(angledPoint[0]-5,angledPoint[1]-5,10,10);

var imageSource = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AMAZON_FASHION/2023/SITE_FLIPS/HOLIDAY23/GW/NOV/CC/CategoryCard_d_1x_HolidayFlip23_Womens_NOV._SY304_CB576715040_.jpg"

var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = imageSource

image.onload = ()=>{
var c = [50,50]
var [x,y] = [c[0] + 50/2,c[1]+ 50/2];

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x, y);
// same angle as the square....
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/4);
ctx.drawImage(image, -50/2,-50/2, 50,50);

// Reset the transformations for future drawings
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/4);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
ctx.restore();

// when the angle is 0 it works...
var c = [150,150]
var [x,y] = [c[0] + 50/2,c[1]+ 50/2];

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.rotate(0);

// completely covers points2 polygon....which is what it is supposed to do!
ctx.drawImage(image, -50/2,-50/2, 50,50);

// Reset the transformations for future drawings
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/4);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "300" height = "300"></canvas>
```

Please also provide an explanation of why my implementation does not work if you provide one that does.
Or at least provide an explanation for why mine does not work so I can try to fix it... right not I am going on nothing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your stroked square representing the `points` array rotates into a different direction as the drawn image.
From `var pAngle = -Math.PI/4;` and what I see on screen I assume it's a 45° anti-clockwise rotation.

Second, if we assume the first point inside the `points` array represents the top-left of the square, we can simply take it's position as the top-left of the image.

So get rid of

```
var c = [50,50]
var [x,y] = [c[0] + 50/2,c[1]+ 50/2];

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x, y);
// same angle as the square....
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/4);
ctx.drawImage(image, -50/2,-50/2, 50,50);
```

and replace it by

```
    var [x, y] = [this.points[0][0] , this.points[0][1]];
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(pAngle);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0, 50, 50);
```

Lastly, the stroked square and the drawn image have different edge lengths, so those won't ever line up.

[image]

If we put everything together:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var points = [
  [50, 50],
  [75, 25],
  [100, 50],
  [75, 75]
];
var points2 = [
  [150, 150],
  [200, 150],
  [200, 200],
  [150, 200]
]
var pAngle = -Math.PI / 4; // (negative b/c canvas origin is top left, not bottom left- cos doesnt change with negative theta, only sin does, so doesnt impact X coord of point)

var angledPoint = [75 + 20 * Math.cos(pAngle), 50 + 20 * Math.sin(pAngle)];

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(this.points[0][0], this.points[0][1]);
for (var point of points) {
  ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillRect(angledPoint[0] - 5, angledPoint[1] - 5, 10, 10);

var imageSource = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AMAZON_FASHION/2023/SITE_FLIPS/HOLIDAY23/GW/NOV/CC/CategoryCard_d_1x_HolidayFlip23_Womens_NOV._SY304_CB576715040_.jpg"

var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = imageSource

image.onload = () => {
  var [x, y] = [this.points[0][0], this.points[0][1]];
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(pAngle);
  var edgeLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.points[1][0] - this.points[0][0], 2) + Math.pow(this.points[1][1] - this.points[0][1], 2));
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, edgeLength, edgeLength);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: I saw the error with the angle.... the way I fixed it was by making the center point as the centroid of the polygon, then translating it by -width/2 and -height/2.... if feel this approach is a little more modular

Comment: Sounds like this did not answer your question - what are you still struggling with?

Comment: I ended up fixing the problem myself.... the problem was that when I applied the rotation, the centerpoint is not calculated correctly... I ended up building a new function to find the centerpoint and rotated it around that, instead of the top left point.